# check if secure connection can be established before redirect

Tags: https

Might be a similar question than others but so far I couldn't find anything that answered my question.

Situation: a user is on my website http://www.example.com. I am about to redirect him to another of my sites: https://secure.example.org

Before the redirect happens, I want to check if the client is actually able to successfully establish a secure connection. (either server-side during the redirect or maybe with an AJAX request prior to redirection or anything that serves the purpose).

Is that possible at all, and how would it be done? Any preference on how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

If the browser can't securely connect to https://secure.example.org it will not.

You can always make an AJAX request but it success or failure will not indicate much about the success of the real request. (And because it's cross domain you will have to add CORS headers).

But **your current configuration is by design insecure**: because your first page use http, **an attacker can replace your link to your secure page by anything he wants**.

If you add https to your first page, then you have nothing else to do, the browser will do all secure check for you.

You should look into HSTS too, to improve the security.

To redirect to https if possible, on the beginning of the http webpage, include a javascript file with an https url, containing the redirection to the https website: users will be redirected only if they support https. (And you can use HSTS with that method too)

Comment: Thanks for the thoughts but that wasn't the concern of my question. My question is about checking if the browser can establish a secure connection or not. I encounter a problem with earlier browser versions that can't establish a https connection for some reason, and I would like to be able to set up a "fallback" so to speak. Instead of showing the user a browser-generated error message I want to redirect them to another page if no secure connection can be established. There's no confidential data sent (actually no user-specific data at all) at this point.

Comment: @koljanep I've add explanations how to redirect to https if possible. Do you need more details?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
   if(empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) || $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == "off"){
  $redirect = 'https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

header('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
header('Location: ' . $redirect);

}

Comment: Thanks, but this is not an answer to my question.